# Why do I get 'google is not defined' in Google's charts own reference example?

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to this topic and following the advice at:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

It tells me there we  can take the following code snippet, past it into a file, save it with an HTML extension and then see a pie chart in a browser. **Unfortunately it does not work.**

The  JavaScript debugger says 'loader.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'  followed, not surprisingly, by  'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at test1.html:8'

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So why does this completely out-of-the-box standard example not work? Is something in this example out of date?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://output.jsbin.com/wuziwarija)

Comment: I would steer away from google charts if possible!!! i found chart js to be far better in so many ways

Comment: I copy pasted your code in code snippet right here and it works fine and shows the pie chart.

Comment: As a last ditch   I tried Internet Explorer – it works in IE.  So maybe my chrome and my Firefox somehow broken....Is there any easy test for brokenness

Comment: A complete clean install of Google Chrome doesn't fix it. Turning off the VPN doesn't fix it. This is a corporate machine so I can't turn off the extra corporate bits – so maybe that's why it doesn't work.
I just tried jchart - that displays a blank screen for all the examples on all three browsers. ho hum

Comment: It works when I run it on a VM - even a corporate VM in data centre (!) so I guess this is over-zealous corporate protection of a local workstation. 

Something to bear in mind when developing an app  for deployment  in a secure corporate setting

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be side effect of corporate protection of a local workstation